# How to get window transparency?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use this function to retrieve a window alpha value, `GetLastError` sometimes says `'Access is denied'` and sometimes `The parameter is incorrect`, in both cases alpha is `204`.

The window which its transparency is being checked is `not` running as admin, and I also tried running the process which is `calling` the function as admin, but i still got the same error.

What could be going on?

```
std::string GetLastErrorAsString(DWORD err) {
    if (err == 0)
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;

    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, err, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);
        LocalFree(messageBuffer);
    
    return message;
}
 
DWORD GetWindowAlpha(HWND hWnd) 
{
    COLORREF color;
    BYTE alpha;
    DWORD flags;
    GetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, &color, &alpha, &flags);
    GetLastErrorAsString(GetLastError());
    return DWORD(alpha);
}
```

The function is ***inside*** of a dll and its checking the window alpha of a different process.

Comment: 4294967295 is -1.

Comment: What's with all the runtime-dynamic linking? [`GetLayeredWindowAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlayeredwindowattributes) can be used as-is. The documentation lists reasons why the call can fail (and how to proceed from there). As it turns out, your code just reports failure (`-1`) but `GetWindowAlpha` doesn't account for the call failing. And `0xCC` is just the fill pattern used by the debug runtime to mark uninitialized data (such as `alpha`).

Comment: I update the question with more details, @AlexF the error is `Acess denied`

Comment: If you attempt to query other information from the same `hWnd`, perhaps `GetWindowRect`, does that succeed or fail, and if it fails, is it the same error?

Answer (score 1):

`SetLayeredWindowAttributes` is not the only way to make windows transparent. MSDN has a note at the bottom of the `GetLayeredWindowAttributes` documentation:

> `GetLayeredWindowAttributes` can be called only if the application has previously called `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` on the window. The function will fail if the layered window was setup with `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

Calling it on a window without `WS_EX_LAYERED` might be undefined.

Comment: Sometimes last error says `Acess is denied` and sometimes `The parameter is incorrect` weird.